# Angular 2 RC4 Component Interaction with Inputs

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component sending an input to another component. Or at least I thought so. Can someone help me figure out the error? I followed along on [this page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html) and can't seem to figure it out.

The error I am getting is:

```
Can't bind to 'item' since it isn't a known native property
```

Here is my relevant parent TS and HTML (note I trimmed it down for this post):

```
import {Child} from'./child'

@Component({
    ...,
    directives: [..., Child]
})

export class ParentMain {
}


<div class="container">

 <child [item]="false"></child>

</div>
```

And here is the relevant child TS and HTML:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    ...,
    selector: "child"
})

export class Child {
    @Input() public item: boolean;
}



<div *ngIf='item'>
    <a href="#" >Test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: can u provide a plunkr or liv preview, at first look, it seems like nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: However, `<child [item]="false"></child>` can be `<child item=""></child>` or `<child [item]="ur_property"></child>`, when we use [],mean it bind to a proeprty in your ts file, mean in your parent component, add this line ur_property: boolean = false

Comment: hmm there might be an error somewhere else in my project - because I just did the same thing on the plunkr that the angular docs have on that page and it works :

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/IHzFeC2Uekt134j6G3AR/

Comment: So I recently switched from RC1 to RC4. Do you know if anything in that change might have affected this?

Comment: there are some changes but might ot be relevant to your case. One significant breaking change is *ngFor="#item of itemList" changed to *ngFor="let item of itemList"

Comment: probably remove the node_modules folder and npm install install again

Comment: thanks man I think that definitely helped. It at least helped me figure out the real error - which was a routing error which just wasn't surfacing due to some node_modules weirdness.